# calculateInSampleSize() For Bitmap Image Issue

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I am facing a huge problem to displaying bitmap image in ImageView in my app. I have an activity which is displaying 8 photos in 2 column and 4 rows. When i click on any photo out of these 8 photos, the photo should be as large as device size. But here i have a issue is that when i click on any photo it give me sometime OutOfMemoryError Error. Please refere my below code where i displaying this large photo inside the imageView :

```
public class ViewFullImage extends Activity {

    private Bitmap bitmap_general;
    private ImageView iv;
    private static final String path = "mfc/cam_img/";
    private int s_id;
    private int intentKey;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_draw_picture);

//  Display  display= ((WindowManager) getSystemService(ViewFullImage.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
//  width = display.getWidth(); 
//  height = display.getHeight(); 

    Display mDisplay= ((Activity) this).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    width= mDisplay.getWidth();
    height= mDisplay.getHeight();

    Log.v("","===================== viewFullImage.java================");

    Log.v("","This is height ViewImage : "+height/2);
    Log.v("","This is width ViewImage : "+width/2);

    s_id=getIntent().getIntExtra("s_id", -1);
    intentKey=getIntent().getIntExtra("iv", -1);

    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

    new LongOperation().execute();

    }

    //Image Rotation
    Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        Bitmap bitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, 
                bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 
                                      matrix, true);
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap=null;

        return bitmap1;
    }

    //Calculate Image size
    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio  = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        System.gc();
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampleImage(File f, int width, int height) {
        try {
            System.gc(); // First of all free some memory

            // Decode image size

            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // The new size we want to scale to

            final int requiredWidth = width;
            final int requiredHeight = height;

            // Find the scale value (as a power of 2)

            int sampleScaleSize = 1;

            while (o.outWidth / sampleScaleSize / 2 >= requiredWidth && o.outHeight / sampleScaleSize / 2 >= requiredHeight)
                sampleScaleSize *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = sampleScaleSize;

            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("", e.getMessage()); // We don't want the application to just throw an exception
        }

        return null;
    }

    int h;
    int w;

    class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewFullImage.this);

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                File Dir= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File imageDirectory = new File(Dir,path);
                File file  = new File(imageDirectory, "img_"+s_id+"_"+intentKey+".jpg");

                String ImgFile_Name = file.getAbsolutePath();
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),options);

                h = options.outHeight;
                w = options.outWidth;

                options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width/5, height/5);
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                options.inScaled=true;

                if(bitmap_general!=null){
                    bitmap_general.recycle();
                    bitmap_general=null;
                }

                bitmap_general = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImgFile_Name,options);

                try {
                    if(h<w)
                    {
                        iv.setImageBitmap(rotateBitmap(bitmap_general));
                    }
                    else{
                        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap_general);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    if(bitmap_general!=null){
                        bitmap_general.recycle();
                        bitmap_general=null;
                    }
                    System.gc();
                }
                finally{
                    if(bitmap_general!=null){
                        bitmap_general.recycle();
                        bitmap_general=null;
                    }
                    System.gc();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("Loading Image...");
            Dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String resultGot) {
        Dialog.dismiss();
    }
 }
}
```

Xml Layout File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/RootView">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here in above code i m bit confuse in what Height and Width value should be i need to enter in below statement :

```
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);
```

Please anybody tell me where i m doing bad thing in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not using decodeSampleImage at all and instead of it you are calling BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),options); Thus you are not handling properly the large images. [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) you can find useful information about how to load large images efficiently. You can use it as a starting point.

Comment: decodeSampleImage(f, width, height) in this method what should be height and width ?

Comment: Those are the required values for your image, the final size to which you want to scale it.